# Adding numbering to documents in Xpages

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I needs some tips on this one, since I couldn't find anything on this, though it's probably pretty simple to do, but I can't think of a way.
Ok, so I need a hidden field which will automatically compute so called id numbers for every document, the numbers must start from 00001 and forward and must never ever repeat. For instance i create a document with numberId = 00001 and another document which creates numberId = 00002, if I ever delete the first or second document, the third created document should have numberId = 00003. No matter how many documents get deleted, the next document created should get the latest numberId and add 1 to it.

I hope I was clear about what I need here. I need an advice or a tip on how would I achieve this.

Also, I can't use @Unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that you will need based on some of the comments to the question.

```
function simplegetSequentialNumber(){
    synchronized(applicationScope){
        var newSeqNum:Int = 0;
        if (applicationScope.containsKey("seqNumber")){
            newSeqNum = applicationScope.get("seqNumber") + 1;
            applicationScope.put("seqNumber",  newSeqNum);
            var seqView:NotesView = database.getView("vw_SequentialNumberStore");
            var seqNumberDoc:NotesDocument = seqView.getFirstDocument();
            seqNumberDoc.replaceItemValue("seqNumber",applicationScope.get("seqNumber"));
            seqNumberDoc.save(true,true);
        } else {
            var seqView:NotesView = database.getView("vw_SequentialNumberStore");
            try {
                var seqNumberDoc:NotesDocument = seqView.getFirstDocument();
                applicationScope.put("seqNumber",seqNumberDoc.getItemValueInteger("seqNumber") + 1);
                seqNumberDoc.replaceItemValue("seqNumber",applicationScope.get("seqNumber"));
                seqNumberDoc.save(true,true);
                newSeqNum = applicationScope.get("seqNumber");
            } catch(e) {
                var seqNumberDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
                seqNumberDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","cPanel");
                seqNumberDoc.replaceItemValue("seqNumber",1);
                applicationScope.put("seqNumber", 1);
                seqNumberDoc.save(true,true);
                newSeqNum = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    var seqNNNN:String = ("0000" + newSeqNum.toString()).slice(-4);
    return seqNNNN;
}
```

As you can see it first gets the next sequential number in a synchronized block, adds one to it and then puts the number back into the applicationScope.

Then it converts it to the string, adds the additional 4 zeros and then the right 4 characters from it.  This returns a string and needs to be stored in a text field. You cannot store it in a number field because Notes will automatically drop the leading zeros from the value.

You can test this function by adding it to a server side javascript library and then including it in a simple page that runs a repeat control to repeat a computed field that just calls the function. Here is my test page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/seqNum.jss" clientSide="false" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:30}">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
            value="#{javascript:simplegetSequentialNumber();}" />
        <xp:br id="br1" />
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I did find a small typo in the code where I used seqNNN instead of seqNNNN in the third last line.

Comment: I have updated the code with an example of how to call it. If your only getting a single digit being saved into your document then you have accidently set the field to be a number field. You cannot store 0001 in a number field, notes will automatically convert it to 1. You must store the returned value in a text field.

Comment: this repeats the values on the test page, but in the view column i don't see it like that. Also in the document properties it's not like that...

And I double checked the field, it's a text field...

Comment: can you show the code where your adding the number to the document

Comment: I have a button and on the onclick event I call the function simplegetSequentialNumber();

And that's it...

Comment: I got it done, it's working flawlessly now! :) Thank you for helping everyone! This is the final function http://gkidd.tumblr.com/post/19778412683/numbering-documents-in-xpages

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are on a single server it is quite straight forward. The very moment you have a cluster or replicating databases it gets as complicated as it can be. For the single server case:

create a function nextNumber() that uses the synchronized keyword in SSJS. You cache the last number in memory and only read it from a profile document when starting. You can do that in Java or SSJS. Matt has an article explaining cache and synchonized: http://mattwhite.me/blog/2009/9/14/on-synchronization-in-xpages.html

Answer (score 2):

I have created something similar for an order number generator. Look at storing the last used numberId in a central document and then getting/updating the numberId in a 'synchronized' thread.

Declan Lynch has blogged about the method:
http://www.qtzar.com/blogs/qtzar.nsf/Blog.xsp?entry=in00zx5i0r9c

Comment: Hey Per, I got it to work with this solution (it seemed the easiest way to do it). But I can't seem to be able to tweak it to my needs. It works great, but I need the numbering to go like 00001, 00002, 00003 etc. instead of 1,2,3,4 etc. How can i do this? Tnx for all the help by the way :)

Comment: Use this solution for the numbering part and then add some code that pads your number with the required zeros. You can do this: http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2010/07/simple-javascript-formatting-zero-padding/ which basically does a ("0000" + number).slice (-5); :-)

Comment: I'm stuck, i got it to add four digits, but all it does is add "1" to all the digits, whenever I create a document I get 1111.

This is where I am so far: http://pastebin.com/mGtv1Shb
I've tried "everything", but I guess I can't really think straight now :)

Comment: Don't put the '00001' back into the scope, just store that as '1'. It is a number, not a string. Once you have the next number in a sequence you need to convert to string to add the '0000' bit and then slice it and return a string

Answer (score 1):

We have used a similar approach to the others described here with the addition of a specified numbering server in the numbering control document. I implemented it into a java bean recently to improve both performance and conflict avoidance (and to learn how those things work).

If the user making the request is not on the numbering server they get a temporary number which is very ugly, but most likely unique in that it includes the time in milliseconds. An agent running on the numbering server detects these temporary numbers and issues the official number. We even have an option to send the requester an email with the official number when it is issued.

For a variety of reasons I cannot open source this feature, but you have enough here that you can try it.

Comment: I promote this answer, because dedicated numbering server is a must for large deployments (cluster, hub/spoke, client replicas - yes, with XPages too...).

Answer (score 0):

We do document numbers by accessing a sequence number document that we create to store the next number in.  Here is the ssjs function I use to access it.  The sequence document has a Tag field and a NextNumber field.  Tag usually looks like "USA-2011-", so final number looks like: "USA-2012-00001"

```
function getDocumentNumber(tag:String){
    var doc:NotesDocument = document1;
    if(doc.getItemValueString("DocumentNumber")=="-"){
        var seqView:NotesView = database.getView("(Sequence Number)");
        var seqNumberDoc:NotesDocument=seqView.getDocumentByKey(tag);
        var seqnum = seqNumberDoc.getItemValueInteger("NextNumber");
        var seqNNNN = @Right("00000" + @Text(seqnum),5);
        var docNumber:String = tag + seqNNNN;
        seqNumberDoc.replaceItemValue("NextNumber",seqNumberDoc.getItemValueInteger("NextNumber") + 1);
        seqNumberDoc.save(true,true);
        return docNumber;
    }
}
```

Call the function from the the querySaveDocument event or some other appropriate event.

Comment: Mike, if you make use of a 'synchronized' code block in your code, you can ensure that the code inside the 'synchronized' code block will only execute once at a time. This will remove the issue of two (or more) users getting the same sequence number.

Comment: @Per Is that a problem you run into when it's a web app?  We are new to doing web apps.  We never experienced any of these type problems using this method with Lotuscript and the client.