# Docuemt postopen event not operating on profile document

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I need to save serial number of the document in a profile document and here is a code of action Execute Script:

```
if (document1.isNewNote()){
   var pdoc:NotesDocument=database.getProfileDocument("LastNumber","")
   var lnm=pdoc.getItemValue("lastNumber")[0];
   var inputText6:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("inputText6");
    inputText6.setValue(lnm);
    pdoc.replaceItemValue("lastNumber",lnm);
    pdoc.save();
    }
```

This code is not opening profile document at all. Any thing wrong in the code?

Comment: Be careful with profile documents as they are cached by the HTTP task. So you will most likely get problems when reading values from the profile doc.

Answer (score 1):

"LastNumber" is the name of the form used to create Profile Document ?
this profile document already exist ?
there are no reader fields in this profile document ?
you have an error on this line : var pdoc:NotesDocument=database.getProfileDocument("LastNumber","") ?
or you have debug it and see that pdoc is null ?

instead of pdoc.getItemValue("lastNumber")[0] you can use pdoc.getItemValueInteger("lastNumber") to get a typed result
I supposed that this field contains a number and you want to increment it

instead of using inputText field you can set value directly with document1.setValue("NumberField", lnm);

Answer (score 1):

I second the caution Per is suggesting. Profile documents can be a beast. You should abstract access to the "next number" into a SSJS function call. Btw. in your code snippet you don't actually increment the last number. Also: if your input text control is bound, go after the data source, not the UI.

A crude way (I would use a managed application bean for better isolation) for a better function could be this:

```
if(document1.isNewNote() {
     document1.setValue("DocumentNumber",applicationTools.getNextNumber());
}
```

Then in a SSJS library you would have:

```
var applicationTools = { 
    "getNextNumber" : function() {
        synchronized(applicationScope){
           var pdoc:NotesDocument=database.getProfileDocument("LastNumber","");
           if (!applicationScope.lastNumber) {
                applicationScope.lastNumber = pdoc.getItemValueInteger("lastNumber");
           }
           applicationScope.lastNumber++;
           pdoc.replaceItemValue("lastNumber",applicationScope.lastNumber);
           pdoc.save(); //Make sure pdoc is writeable by ALL!!!!
           pdoc.recycle();
           return applicationScope.lastNumber;
        }
    },

    "someOtherUtility" : function(nameToLookup, departments) {
       // more stuff here
    }
}
```

Which, in some way [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805356/adding-numbering-to-documents-in-xpages), but not for a profile field. Someone still could simply go after the `applicationScope.lastNumber` variable, which is one of the reasons why I rather use a bean. The other: you could do the saving asynchronously, so it would be faster.

Note: in any case the number generation only works when you have a non-replicating database. But abstracting the function opens the possibility to replace fetching the number from the profile with a call to a central number generator ... or any other mechanism ... without changing your form again.